# Find elements of a list between two boundaries (which are formed from other two boundary case lists) in very efficient way

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, performance, sequence

Given a list of numbers and sequences that represent boundary ranges for the list of number, find the numbers that fit in the various boundaries(inclusive).
For example, Given number_list = [3,8,9] lowerboundary_numbers = [3,6] and upper boundary = [4,10]. We now try to find numbers from the number_list that fit in the range [3,4] in the first run and then numbers that fit in the range and [6,10] in the second run and return a list of the numbers that fit in the boundaries of the two runs. In this case, 3 is the only number that fits in [3,4] and 8&9 fit in [6,10] so we return [1,2]. The code below runs but it is not fast enough.

```
def fun(number_list, lowerboundary, upperboundary):
    return_array = [0] * len(lowerboundary)
    for a in number_list:
        for b in range(len(lowerboundary)):
            if lowerboundars[b] <= a <= upperboundary[b]:
                 return_array[b] += 1
    return return_array

print(fun([3, 8, 9], [3,6], [4,10]))
#outputs [1,2]
```

Comment: Are there going to be multiple runs of boundaries ?

Comment: yes. So you can have for example a lower_boundary = [2,4,8,5,7,6] and an upper boundary = [2,9,10,15,20,8] now you have 6 boundaries that are formed from the two list: [2,2], [4,9],[8,10],[5,15],[7,20],[6,8] so we check if each number in the inital number list is within these boundaries and increment our count for each boundary case by 1 and return an array that has 6 elements (because we have 6 boundaries) where each element is the count of elements that fit in that boundary